Error after updating to flutter 3.22: child._parent != this using LayoutBuilder
I recently upgraded my Flutter project from version 3.16 to 3.22 and encountered an intermittent error during navigation between screens:
child._parent == this': is not true.

Has anyone else encountered those issue after upgrading to Flutter 3.22?
Are there known conflicts between GoRouter, LayoutBuilder, and Flutter 3.22?
Are there any workarounds or fixes for this error?
